# Is this sentence with "though" correct?

Tags: subject-verb-inversion

In this sentence, is "Understand it though I do" grammatically correct?

> **Understand it though I do**, the logic of such a conception I could not explain even if I tried to.

If so, in what ways can **though** be used similarly?

Comment: From the *idiomatic* perspective, it's a very clumsy construction, so I think probably it's either from a relatively competent *learner,* or an relatively *incompetent* native speaker (unsuccessfully trying to emulate a formal register that he's not actually very familiar with). The idiomatic standard here would be ***Even though*** (or ***Although***) *I understand it [I could not explain the logic of such a conception]*. It might have been a bit more likely from competent speakers a couple of centuries ago, but I'm not sure of that.

Comment: Agreed. Today, this sounds like something that would be used for comedic effect by a Sheldon-like character.

Answer (score 3):

This sentence is using *inversion* (twice). It is perfectly grammatical, but may look more familiar/readable written as:

> Though I do understand it, I could not explain the logic of such a conception even if I tried to.

Here's the first inversion:

> **Understand it though I do**, the logic of such a conception I could not explain even if I tried to.

And here's the second inversion:

> Understand it though I do, **the logic of such a conception I could not explain** even if I tried to.

You can read more about inversion [here](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/inversion).

Comment: Familiar with the term *inversion* I was not, but its meaning I will now retain. Cool. +1